# use OR in laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

My table definition is as below

```
**PURCHASE_PYAMENTS**

SELLER      MASTER_PAYMENT      BILL        COUNT_VB        PAYMENT_STATUS      REMAIN_PARTIAL_AMOUNT

abc         15000               0           0               1                   0   
xyz         14000               1           1               1                   14000
abc         15000               0           0               0                   5000
```

I need `sum` of `master_payment` column for specific `seller` under two condition:

1. `payment_status = 1` and `count_vb = 0`
2. `payment_status = 0` and `remain_partial_amount > 0`

If any of above condition goes true then `master_payment` should add in `sum` so, how can I achieve it using single query?.

I try it by my self but get a result for only one condition my query is as below:

```
  $total_count_vb = DB::table('purchase_payments')
        ->where('seller',$seller_list)
        ->where('count_vb',0)
        ->where('payment_status',1)
        ->SUM('master_payment');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `where()` and `orWhere()` closures for [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
Payment::where('seller', 'abc')->
       ->where(function ($q) {
           $q->where(function ($q) {
               $q->where('payment_status', 1)->where('count_vb', 0);
           })
           ->orWhere(function ($q) {
               $q->where('payment_status', 0)->where('remain_partial_amount', '>', 0);
           });
       });
       ->sum('master_payment');
```